# Como firmar una petición correctamente con OAUTH 1.0

Tags: php, oauth, signature

Necesito firmar una petición, estoy utilizando la libreria Oauth de **Andy Smith** y necesito generar la autorización para el header.

El problema es que siempre obtengo ***Message signature not valid*** en mi TC, por lo cual supongo que estoy generando mal los parámetros de entrada para firmar la solicitud.

```
  $method = 'http';
  $url = 'http://cvirtual.cl/mod/lti/service.php';
  $request = new OAuthRequest($method, $url);
  $token = new OAuthToken('asd123', '8cUIaGVLhmg4pe7gqoOu3ldxJTOXyNmu');
  $consumer = new OAuthConsumer('asd123', '8cUIaGVLhmg4pe7gqoOu3ldxJTOXyNmu', 'about:blank');
  $signature = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
  $request = $request->from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, $method, $url);
  $request->sign_request($signature, $consumer, $token);
  echo("<textarea rows='5' cols='100'>{$request->to_header()}</textarea>");
```

Si alguien puede resolver las siguientes dudas para entender mejor el protocolo seria de gran ayuda.

1. ¿El method es con o sin ://? (Ej: http:// o http)
2. ¿La url incluye http://?
3. ¿La url es de quien emite la solicitud o la url a quien se le hace la solicitud?
4. Que sucede con las rutas amigables, ¿Se debe incluir .php en el enlace para firmar la petición?

La libreria me entrega el siguiente header:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="7243daf569edbad7309bc19fd724244e",oauth_timestamp="1561125182",oauth_consumer_key="asd123",oauth_token="asd123",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="yn0cSIQg3Aj6FIWalE%2FIrktaFbA%3D"
```

Estoy intentando enviar una solicitud con **POSTMAN**, ¿Esta debe partir por OAuth o directamente en los parametros clave valor como oauth_version?[image: Imagen de POSTMAN]

Cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando de forma local y sin HTTPS

Comment: ¿como obtienes el valor del token? >OAuthToken('asd123', '8cUIaGVLhmg4pe7gqoOu3ldxJTOXyNmu'); Es que tengo un problema con la autenticación Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas...

**1.- ¿El method es con o sin ://? (Ej: http:// o http)**

*El metodo utilizado es el verbo HTTP (GET, POST, etc) no el tipo de petición (http, https)*

**2.- ¿La url incluye http://?**

*Si, la url requiere de http o https en su defecto.*

**¿La url es de quien emite la solicitud o la url a quien se le hace la solicitud?**

*La url es del dominio a quien le harás la petición*

**Que sucede con las rutas amigables, ¿Se debe incluir .php en el enlace para firmar la petición?**

*La ruta debe ser idéntica, si es amigable no debe incluir .php*